# javascript.split not returning expected values

Tags: javascript, split

I have a javascript value holding a string:

```
value = "123 / 15 - Value1"
```

And I'm trying to split on delimiters so that I can have each number and the string value is their own variables.

I tried this:

```js
value = "123 / 15 - Value1"
splitVal = value.split(/[" ".,\/ -]/);
number1 = splitVal[0];
number2 = splitVal[1];
name = splitVal[2];
```

But when I console log number1,number2 and name I only get '123' in the console, the other 2 are blank.

What am I doing wrong here as far as splitting a string by both a hyphen and a slash, as well as spaces?

Comment: What _pattern_ are you expecting in the string? It would be easy to hardcode a solution for this specific case, but from the context it's not clear how you're trying to parse `value` in a generic way.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts the pattern in this case should always be  number / number - name with spaces between each value and delimiter but there could be cases where it could be number/number-name

Comment: `[" "]` I think you either want `"` or ` ` (space) here. This regex will match either of the two and uselessly repeats `"`.

Comment: Also, since you have a single character class (simplified) `[ /]` the sequence between the two numbers `123 / 15` matches *three times*, hence why you get empty results. If you put a quantifier after the square brackers `...]+` you would only get three items after splitting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `match()` instead of `split()`:

```js
var value = "123 / 15 - Value1"

var splitVal= value.match(/[a-z0-9]+/gi);

console.log(splitVal)
```

Comment: Yep, perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `String.prototype.match()` and a destructuring assignment with the following `RegExp`:

```js
const value = '123 / 15 - Value1'
const [, number1, number2, name] = value.match(/(\d+) *\/ *(\d+) *- *(.+)/)

console.log(number1, number2, name)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you split at (space)  and `/` so `123 / 15` becomes:

```
[
  '123',
  // space
  '',
  // /
  '',
  // space
  '15'
]
```

If you know how the pattern should look like you might want to use [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) instead of split:

```js
value = "123 / 15 - Value1"
matchVal = value.match(/^(\d+)\s*\/\s*(\d+)\s*-\s*(.*)$/);
console.dir(matchVal)
```

With match you can exactly define how the input has to be formatted and which fields of the input you want to extract.

Furthermore it allows `name` to be something like `Value-1 with spaces` if this is required, (if this is not allowed you could change the `(.*)` a more restrictive match):

```js
value = "123 / 15 - Value-1 with spaces"
matchVal = value.match(/^(\d+)\s*\/\s*(\d+)\s*-\s*(.*)$/);
console.dir(matchVal)
```

Using [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/I5bJH2/1) an help you to understand what earch part of the regexp does.

Comment: This should have been the accepted answer. It explains the problem and gives a tailored solution with a description of how it works (even though I posted an almost identical RegExp before this :P)

Comment: @Patrick Roberts I disagree. Matching the string like so /(\d+)|(\w+)/g with a global flag seems to me a much more reusable solution.

Comment: @etarhan depends on the usecase. If you want to have lazy matching then this might be true. But if you want to ensure that the input always matches a certain pattern - what you should always do to keep the code maintainable and prevent that this lazy matching is abused - then you want to test against a more restrictive pattern. That way you will find errors at an early stage. What if the input is illformed  because of a bug (or on purpose) and is `10 10 / 10 Name` then you might get an error (or an unwanted execution path) at an unexpected place in your code.

Comment: @etarhan that kind of attitude is what introduces vulnerabilities into string sanitization libraries. Like t.niese says don't be lazy.

Answer (score 1):

With

```
console.table("123 / 15 - Value1".split(/[" ".,\/ -]/))
```

you'll find out what really happens is that all values except for indexes 0,3,6 are empty strings

Answer (score 0):

You might have more luck just using a regex to pull out the values instead of trying to use delimiters.

```
let str = '123 / 15 - Value1';
let reg = /\w+/g;

let res;
let results = [];
while ((res = reg.exec(str)) !== null) {
    results.push(res);
}

if (results.length > 0) {
    console.log('Results = ' + results);
} else {
    console.log('No results.')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
splitVal= value.split(/[" ".,\/ -]+/);
```

Add a '+' to the end of your regex. It tells the regex there must be at least one occurrence (i.e. no empty strings allowed) which is why your split is returning empty strings (as received from your regex).

Answer (score 0):

```
var value = "123 / 15 - Value1";
var r = value.split(/\s?[\/-]\s?/);
console.log(r);
/*
[ '123', '15', 'Value1' ]
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex in your code is resulting in `["123", "", "", "15", "", "", "Value1"]` .You can see in `1` & `2` index they are empty space. You can slightly modify the regex

```js
var value = "123 / 15 - Value1";

var splitVal = value.split(/[\/-]/),
  number1 = splitVal[0].trim(),
  number2 = splitVal[1],
  name = splitVal[2];

console.log(number1, number2, name)
```

Answer (score -1):

You should remove white spaces before split, like this:

```
splitVal= value.replace(/ /g,'').split(/[" ".,\/ -]/);
```

Comment: While this would give the correct result for the given case, you still should explain why it won't give the correct result if the spaces are not replaced.

Comment: What happens if the input is `"123 // 15 - Value1"`?

Comment: @vlaz [according to OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52334195/javascript-split-not-returning-expected-values/52334317#comment91615539_52334195) that's not a valid input. Parsing that string does not have to be well-defined.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I was prodding for this answer to be re-thought and/or expanded. The issue *isn't* that there are spaces - it's how the regex is defined. Solving *that* is a much better solution. Although explanation for why this solution works is also going to be valuable.

Comment: A bigger issue is that this solution would remove spaces from the `name` before matching it.